# How avoid row-level locking in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table containing 3 columns eid,salary,newsal.

I have already inserted eid and salary for all the employees.
Now,if I update the salary of any employee I want a trigger which directly increments the salary of that employee by 20% and stores it into the column newsal.

I used a trigger :

```
create or replace trigger pp1
after update on empsal
for each row
BEGIN
:new.newsal := :old.sal*1.2;
END;
```

I can't execute this trigger as it says

> Error report: ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger
>   type
>   04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
>   *Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
>              insert or update triggers.
>   *Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.

My table is defined as:

```
> create table empsal(empno varchar2(8),sal number,newsal number,primary
> key(empno));
```

Comment: Can't you just change the trigger to be `before update` instead of `after update`, just as the error message states? If you use `after update`, then perhaps you can't update the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `AFTER`-triggers cannot write to the `:new`-values. Use a `BEFORE`-trigger instead. Confer, for example, [this documentation on triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) (emphasis mine):

> **BEFORE**
>
> Specify BEFORE to cause the database to fire the trigger before
>   executing the triggering event. For row triggers, the trigger is fired
>   before each affected row is changed.
>
> Restrictions on BEFORE Triggers  BEFORE triggers are subject to the
>   following restrictions:
>
> - You cannot specify a BEFORE trigger on a view or an object view.
> - **You can write to the :NEW value** but not to the :OLD value.
>
> **AFTER**
>
> Specify AFTER to cause the database to fire the trigger after
>   executing the triggering event. For row triggers, the trigger is fired
>   after each affected row is changed.
>
> Restrictions on AFTER Triggers  AFTER triggers are subject to the
>   following restrictions:
>
> - You cannot specify an AFTER trigger on a view or an object view.
> - **You cannot write either the :OLD or the :NEW value.**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trg
   BEFORE UPDATE
   ON empsal
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.newsal := :new.sal * 1.2;
END;
```

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO empsal (empno, sal)
     VALUES (123, 120);
```

[image]

```
UPDATE empsal
   SET sal = 130;


+-------+-----+--------+
| EMPNO | SAL | NEWSAL |
+-------+-----+--------+
|   123 | 130 |    156 |
+-------+-----+--------+
```

If you are using Oracle 11g, leverage the concept of virtual column, so try as

```
CREATE TABLE empsal
(
   empno    VARCHAR2 (8),
   sal      NUMBER,
   newsal   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sal * 1.2) VIRTUAL,
   PRIMARY KEY (empno)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what I want to do is when I update the sal from 120 to 130 I want the operation to happen on 130 and so newsal = 156

Comment: @captainn3mo I have updated the trigger code, try whether you are getting 156 or not. If it is correct, accept the answer.